# Call method right after blocking call

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-thread

I'm using a third party library which has a blocking function, that is, it won't return until it's done; I can set a timeout for that call.

Problem is, that function puts the library in a certain state. As soon as it enters that state, I need to do something from my own code. My first solution was to do that in a separate thread:

```
void LibraryWrapper::DoTheMagic(){
    //...
    boost::thread EnteredFooStateNotifier( &LibraryWrapper::EnterFooState, this );
    ::LibraryBlockingFunction( timeout_ );
    //...
}

void LibraryWrapper::EnterFooState(){
   ::Sleep( 50 ); //Ensure ::LibraryBlockingFunction is called first
   //Do the stuff
}
```

Quite nasty, isn't it? I had to put the `Sleep` call because ::LibraryBlockingFunction must definitely be called before the stuff I do below, or everything will fail. But waiting 50 milliseconds is quite a poor guarantee, and I can't wait more because this particular task needs to be done as fast as possible.

Isn't there a better way to do this? Consider that I don't have access to the Library's code. Boost solutions are welcome.

**UPDATE**: Like one of the answers says, the library API is ill-defined. I sent an e-mail to the developers explaining the problem and suggesting a solution (i.e. making the call non-blocking and sending an event to a registered callback notifying the state change). In the meantime, I set a timeout high enough to ensure stuff X is done, and set a delay high enough before doing the post-call work to ensure the library function was called. It's not deterministic, but works most of the time.

Comment: I'm confused.  Why can't you do the obvious and just do what you have to do after the blocking call has returned?  Why the second thread?

Comment: @John: I interpreted the problem as requiring to change the state after the call but before it had returned. I could be wrong though...

Comment: @John: It's like Alex said. I need to do it as soon as possible (hardware stuff)

Comment: Does it have to occur strictly between the time after you entered the blocking call and before the blocking call returns?

Comment: @John: Yes. Let me give you more details: the blocking function places hardware A in state S for some time. In that state, it expects hardware B to do stuff X. For this process to succeed, B must perform X on A while it's in the S state. This would be easy if I had separate libraries for A and B, but this library controls both of them, and the stuff I do with B is an ad hoc hardware solution invoked via software.

Comment: I'll post a possible solution, but I don't know if it will work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would using boost future clarify this code? To use an example from the [boost future documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.futures):

```
int calculate_the_answer_to_life_the_universe_and_everything()
{
    return 42;
}

boost::packaged_task<int> pt(calculate_the_answer_to_life_the_universe_and_everything);
boost::unique_future<int> fi=pt.get_future();

boost::thread task(boost::move(pt));

// In your example, now would be the time to do the post-call work.

fi.wait(); // wait for it to finish
```

Although you will still presumably need a bit of a delay in order to ensure that your function call has happened (this bit of your problem seems rather ill-defined - is there any way you can establish deterministically when it is safe to execute the post-call state change?).

Comment: Whoah, this looks interesting, +1. I'll start reading about Boost's futures. About the delay, all I know is that `LibraryBlockingFunction`  must be running in order to be able to do the post-call change. I have fluid contact with the library developers, so I can ask for a change in the API, but it might take some time.

Answer (score 2):

The problem as I understand it is that you need to do this:

1. Enter a blocking call
2. After you have entered the blocking call but before it completes, you need to do something else
3. You need to have finished #2 before the blocking call returns

From a purely C++ standpoint, there's no way you can accomish this in a deterministic way.  That is without understanding the details of the library you're using.

But I noticed your timeout value.  That might provide a loophole, maybe.

What if you:

1. Enter the blocking call with a timeout of zero, so that it returns immediately
2. Do you other stuff, either in the same thread or synchronized with the main thread.  Perhaps using a barrier.
3. After #2 is verified to be done, enter the blocking call again, with the normal non-zero timeout.

This will only work if the library's state will change if you enter the blocking call with a zero timeout.

Comment: Can't set timeout to zero: That would mean that hardware A wouldn't wait for hardware B's action at all; the timeout is associated to the time that hardware A will remain in state S, waiting for stuff X to happen.